# Problems updating additional column on just one Laravel pivot record

Tags: php, laravel-5

When trying to update just one record of a pivot_table, this method updates all records with the same `order_id` and `user_id`. Only records that match the `order_id`, `user_id`, `status_id` and `finished_at = null` should be updated.

```
public function pause($id)
{
    $order = Order::find($id);
    $now = Carbon::now();
    $stage = Status::find($order->status_id)->stage_id;

    $users = $order
        ->user()
        ->where('status_id', $order->status_id)
        ->where('finished_at', null)
        ->get();

    foreach($users as $user)
    {
        $user->pivot->finished_at = $now;
        $user->pivot->save();
    }

    flash()->success('Progress paused for order #' . $order->order_number .'.');
    return redirect('/department/' . $stage);

}
```

Before running pause method:
[image: image before running pause method]

After running pause method:
[image: image after running pause method]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just grab all the users from the given Order, you can iterate through them and update their pivot records like so:

```
// set finished_at time for all users
foreach($users as $user)
{
    $user->order()
         ->wherePivot('status_id', $order->status_id)
         ->wherePivot('finished_at', null)
         ->updateExistingPivot($order->id, [ 'finished_at' => $now ], false);
}
```